# "TypeError: response.write is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, response

I'm trying to learn some Node.js and this is my first tutorial project.
Although I changed some minor things, I mainly followed this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFJHQ2g6s0k&ab_channel=ItsTechMode

My JS code is below.

```js
const http = require('http');
const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Athens,GR&appid=a7003b6a9783fdc3503466334cbd605b&units=metric';
let data;

var server = http.createServer(function(request,response){

  var request = require('request');

  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.write("Hello write");
  response.end('Hello World\n');
  
  

  request({ url: url }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

    let data = JSON.parse(body);

    response.write("Trying to print this.");
    response.end();
    

    // response.write("<html><body><div id='container'>");
    // response.write("<h1>" +"City Name - :"+ data['name']+"<br>"+"</h1>");
    // response.write("<h2>"+ "Temperature - :" + data.main['temp'] + "<br>"+"</h2>");
    // response.write("<h2>"+"Sunset Time - :"+ new Date(data.sys["sunset"]+1000)+ "</h2>");
    // response.write("</div></body></html>");
    

    console.log(response.body)
    response.end();
  });
    
}).listen(8000, "127.0.0.1");
```

I get the "TypeError: response.write is not a function"
[Stackoverflow does not allow me to add a pic. so here is a link to the error screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I35gn.jpg)
Can someone help me about it? Also, sorry if the this post's format looks weird. I tried to make it look as best as I could but I'm a newbie around here.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `response` in this line:

`var server = http.createServer(function(request,response){...}`

Is what you need to use to do stuff like "response.write", however here:

`request({ url: url }, (error, response, body) => {`

You have some other parameter which you are naming "response".  That makes the original "response" variable inaccessible.

Change the parameter name in the `request(...)` call to "resp" or something.  And be sure to use "resp.body" within the callback.

Comment: Thank you. It was just what I was confused about. Grateful for your help!